# Error when I try to play a sound

Tags: python

I am trying to make a alarm clock sort of thing but when I try and run the thing I am using i get this error:

```
 File "C:\Python27\Salty.py", line 2, in <module>
    winsound.PlaySound('siren.wav')
 TypeError: PlaySound() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Here is the code I am running.
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('siren.wav')

I know this is probably a simple fix but it is late. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`winsound.PlaySound`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html#winsound.PlaySound) takes *two* parameters: `sound` and `flags`. `sound`

> may be a filename, audio data as a string, or `None`

(from the docs), while `flags` is a bitwise-OR'd combination of `winsound.SND_FILENAME` (the `sound` parameter is the path to a `.wav` file), `winsound.SND_ALIAS` (the `sound` parameter is a name for a builtin Windows sound, see the docs), `winsound.SND_LOOP` (play the sound in a loop), `winsound.SND_MEMORY` (the `sound` parameter is a memory image of a `.wav` file), `winsound.SND_PURGE` (stop all playing instances of the specified sound, *not supported on modern Windows*), `winsound.SND_ASYNC` (return immediately, allowing sounds to play asynchronously), `winsound.SND_NODEFAULT` (do not play default sound if the sound cannot be found), `winsound.SND_NOSTOP` (do not interrupt other sounds currently playing) and `winsound.SND_NOWAIT` (return immediately if the sound driver is busy)

What you want is the `winsound.SND_FILENAME` flag:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('siren.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

or, as a function:

```
import winsound
def playSiren():
    winsound.PlaySound('siren.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

#### Edited to add:

It may be necessary to give the whole path (e.g. `'C:\\whatever\\siren.wav'`) instead of just the file name (as discussed in the comments).

Comment: How could I turn that into a function?

Comment: Not even the default system sound? What does `winsound.PlaySound("SystemHand", winsound.SND_ALIAS)` do (it should play the default error sound)?

Comment: It plays a noise, but not the one i put in there. It plays like sort of an error noise.

Comment: Good, so `winsound` works. Is the `siren.wav` file in your current working directory (try printing `os.getcwd()` in your script)?

Comment: I don't know if I put it in right but if i did, it did not work.

Comment: Try giving the whole file path `PlaySound` (ie. instead of `'siren.wav'` use `'C:\\whatever\\siren.wav'`)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you soo much for helping me! (The siren was extremley loud and scared the crud out of me)